# How to be made secure copying between remote machines on different ports by local machine

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssh, backup, scp

I have a cluster with 4 machines. One of them is cluster manager.
When cluster manager start a backup, each slave cluster creates cluster backup files in it's own file system.

After cluster manager finished backup process, I have to copy cluster backups from each slave cluster to another remote storage machine. Slave clusters and storage machine ssh ports are different.

I'm thinking copy files from remote clusters to remote storage machine by secure copy over cluster manager, like:

```
scp cluster1.com:/backup/files storage.com:/backup/cluster1 
scp cluster2.com:/backup/files storage.com:/backup/cluster2 
scp cluster3.com:/backup/files storage.com:/backup/cluster3 
...
```

As I said ssh port of the clusters and storage machines are different. But `scp` command has only one `port` keyword argument. Is there a way to set both cluster and storage server ports with `scp` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ssh_config`, which allows you to create aliases for hosts used in `scp` and specify separate ports. In short fill in your `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host host1
  Hostname host
  Port 2222
Host host2
  Hostname host
  Port 2223
```

and then you can simply use

```
scp host1:/backup/files host2:/backup/cluster1
```

You can store also other information in the config, such as users, identity files and so on.